# Segmenting within dataset

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy, dataframe

I am looking for an algorithm to parse through variables within a list of 0s(indicating False) and 99s(indicating True) to segment them into 2 categories. This list essentially indicates whether values in another list exceeds a certain threshold as observed in Figure 1 below.

I would like to obtain the list of values for Category 1 which contains the very 1st segment of 99s detected and every alternate segments of 99s after. Whereas, the list of values for Category 2 will contain the initial 2nd segment of 99s detected and every alternate segments of 99s after. As an example to illustrate, Figure 2 and Figure 3 below are the Category 1 and Category 2 values that I would like to obtain. You may find my code to replicate the plot below.

Figure 1:

[image]

Figure 2:

[image]

Figure 3:

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50,100,size=(100, 1)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50,100,size=(100, 1)))
zeros1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(80))
zeros2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(50))
zeros3 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(150))
zeros4 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(80))
zeros5 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(50))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50,100,size=(100, 1)))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50,100,size=(100, 1)))
df5=pd.concat([zeros1, df, zeros2, df2, zeros3, df3, zeros4, df4, zeros5 ], ignore_index=True)
times = pd.date_range('2012-10-01', periods=len(df5), freq='1min')
df6 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(times), df5], axis = 1, ignore_index=True)

segment = []

for i in range(0,len(df6)):
    if df6.iloc[i,1]> 50:
        segment.append(99)
    else:
        segment.append(0)
        
plt.plot(df6[0], df6[1])
plt.plot(df6[0], segment, color = 'r')
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you considered clustering using K-Means? You can start with K=1, and calculate the coverage of samples. If your K does not cover enough samples, incerement it, until satisfactory. This kinds of depends on how messy your data is. Is it always this tidy? If so, classical methods could be enough here, but it would be better if you described a bit.

Comment: I did tried using Kmeans but it was't accurate in determining them. I am actually trying to create the dependent variables to train my classification models based on my knowledge of the dataset. I managed to classify them like Figure 1 but I'm missing the last step to segment them into the 2 categories that I need as shown in Figure 2 and 3. I was thinking if there's an algorithm that I can use to do this.

Comment: Just to clarify, you used Kmeans to classify the data of figure 1, right? This, I think, would work. Not on the raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will iterate through a list of 0s and 99s and note the start and end of each sequence of 99, and store it in a different list depending on its parity:

```py
def get_alternate_segments(l):
  state_v,state_p = (0,0) # cycling through states (0,0), (99,0), (0,1), (99,1)
  segments = ([],[])
  for i,v in enumerate(l):
    if state_v == 0:
      if v == 99:
        start = i
        state_v = 99
    elif state_v == 99:
      if v == 0:
        end = i
        segments[state_p].append((start, end))
        state_v = 0
        state_p = 1 - state_p
  if state_v == 99:
    end = len(l)
    segments[state_p].append((start, end))
  return segments
```

**Testing**

```py
>>> l = [0,99,99,99,0,0,99,99,0,0,0,99,0,99,0,99,99,99]
>>> get_alternate_segments(l)
([(1, 4), (11, 12), (15, 18)], [(6, 8), (13, 14)])
```

**How does it work?** We remember if we're currently seeing a segment of 0s or 99s thanks to variable `state_v`. We also remember if we are currently seeing an even or an odd segment thanks to variable `state_p`.

- When a 99-segment begins, we note the value of `i` as the start of the segment.
- When a 99-segment ends, we note the value of `i` as the end of the segment and we store the segment as a pair `(start, end)` into `segment[0]` or  `segment[1]` depending on parity.

Note that the pairs `(start, end)` are indexed consistently with python's convention for ranges and list slices; *i.e.*, from `start` included to `end` excluded.